# html5 - I can block resize of my page?

Tags: html, css

My layout is responsive, can block the resizing of the page or better, put a minimum size for it?

*Example*

having elements on my page that when you change the page size it totally misalignment. I want the page not be less than 500px wide.

PS: I try set min-width in my body, but not work :/

Comment: How responsive can your page be, if it doesn't respond well to user changes of the viewport?

Comment: Set your css for whatever your wrapper or main div is to have a min-width: 500px.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [min-width](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-width.asp) CSS property

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="min-width: 600px">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Place a div inside the body and put a min-width on that. Place your page contents inside of said div.

Comment: How to do it? could put an example?

Comment: I added an example for you in my answer.